# Returning mongodb _id into a data.frame

Tags: r, mongodb

```
school_id    <- mongo.distinct(mongo,dbns,"_id") ;
school_table <- data.frame(key=c(1:length(school_id)),ID=c(school_id))
```

First query is giving me results i.e. list of all the ids present in the collection.
But when trying to add this result to data frame. I am getting following error.

```
# Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :    cannot
# coerce class ""mongo.oid"" to a data.frame
```

Please suggest how  shall I get the list of ids in data frame.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the structure of `school_id` and what result is in `school_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the IDs to a character, and then put into a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(key=c(1:length(school_id)),ID=do.call(rbind, lapply(school_id, as.character)))
```

Consider this working example

```
## create dummy data and insert into database
library(rmongodb)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 val =letters[1:10])


mongo <- mongo.create(db = "test")
coll <- "test.fetching_id"

## insert it a few times to gernate documents
for(i in 1:10){
    mongo.insert(mongo = mongo,
                ns = coll, 
                b = mongo.bson.from.df(df))
}


## find the data
raw_ids <- mongo.distinct(mongo = mongo,
                          ns = coll,
                          "_id")

mongo.destroy(mongo)

data.frame(key = c(1:length(raw_ids)), 
           ID = do.call(rbind, lapply(raw_ids, as.character)))

#   key                       ID
# 0   1 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd96
# 1   2 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd97
# 2   3 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd98
# 3   4 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd99
# 4   5 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd9a
# 5   6 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd9b
# 6   7 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd9c
# 7   8 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd9d
# 8   9 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd9e
# 9  10 57562e6fceeb7846c87afd9f
```